# Whats the regular expression for finding string between > and <

Tags: python, regex, xml-parsing

I have a HTML file

```
 ...<b>Breakfast</b><hr>...
```

I want `Breakfast` which is between `>` and `<`.

I tried

```
...for test_string in line:
        if re.match(r'(>.*<$)',test_string):...
```

That didn't give `>Breakfast<` either.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you include `$`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the regular expression for finding string between " "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066328/whats-the-regular-expression-for-finding-string-between)

Comment: You should look at something like this: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: As usual, with anything involving HTML and Regexes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 4):

In general regular expression can't parse html. You could use an html parser instead:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup # pip install BeautifulSoup

html = """...<b>Breakfast</b><hr>..."""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup(text=True) # get all text
# -> [u'...', u'Breakfast', u'...']
print [b.text for b in soup('b')] # get all text for <b> tags
# -> [u'Breakfast']
```

Answer (score 3):

The `$` means "end of input" and doesn't belong in this regex.

Instead, do the following:

```
m = re.search(r'>([^<]*)<', test_string)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

This searches for `>`, then all the following characters that are not `<`, and then `<`. The characters betweens `>` and `<` are marked as a group, which you get using `m.group(1)`

Comment: How is `[^<]*<` better than `.*?<` in this use case? Surely they are translated to the same code internally.

Comment: That's interesting; is one actually any more efficient?

Comment: @kindall, yes, the `[^<]*` is slightly more efficient http://pastebin.com/jNArurPw

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
r'(>.*?<)'
```

Or maybe

```
r'<b(>.*?<)/b>'
```

which is non-greedy and matches in the middle of a string. Note that [parsing HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/21475) is not very robust.